# How to play sound in while performing certain Animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am making an App which does certain processing for 5 seconds and then giving a result.
During that time I want to apply some `Animation` and play some sound to avoid user to sit idle watching whats happening.

I have applied the `Animation` and need some help in how to play sound for that particular time.
I have one sound file for 5 seconds.

Any ideas are very welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading the documentation of:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html

This handles playing sounds on the OS.

Answer (score 5):

```
Animation myAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.myanimation);
animationFalling.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
         //here you can play your sound
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
         // here you can stop playing your sound
    }
};
```

About how to play your sound, there is [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) or [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) in order to play them.