# how to define button display to appear one by one with animation?

Tags: android, animation, duration

i have 9 buttons in my activity, i use push right animation to show my buttons on Create, i change duration to set display, so i have 9 animation.xml with diffrent duration (from 1000 to 5000 for ex).

also i have to repeat 3 line code for 9 time in activity ,

```
final Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button06);
    Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in);
    b.startAnimation(anim);
```

so, i need to know is there any easier way to make something like that with Less code?
for ex, use 1 animation.xml and define button to run animation One after another?!

my full code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button06);
        Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in);
        b.startAnimation(anim);

        final Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button03);
        Animation anim1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in1);
        b1.startAnimation(anim1);

        final Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Animation anim2=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in2);
        b2.startAnimation(anim2);

        final Button b3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button08);
        Animation anim3=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in3);
        b3.startAnimation(anim3);

        final Button b4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button04);
        Animation anim4=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in4);
        b4.startAnimation(anim4);

        final Button b5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        Animation anim5=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in5);
        b5.startAnimation(anim5);

        final Button b6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button07);
        Animation anim6=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in6);
        b6.startAnimation(anim6);

        final Button b7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button05);
        Animation anim7=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in7);
        b7.startAnimation(anim7);

        final Button b8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        Animation anim8=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.push_right_in8);
        b8.startAnimation(anim8);


        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startButtonAnimation(b);
            }
        });

    }
    public void startButtonAnimation(Button btn){
        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
        btn.setAnimation(shake);
        btn.startAnimation(shake);

        shake.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity2.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try my solution?

Comment: i already use an other method to do animation on press and also change activity, so i confuse, i put my all code, if you fix it and give me full code, it will be so great, thanks

Comment: Lets try my solution now

Comment: But one more think now you set only one click listener for only one button -  if you want to set it for all give me information I will update my post

Comment: i did imports but still have eror :

Comment: http://up.vbiran.ir/uploads/10085142589972933314_df.PNG

Comment: yes i want for all, use button1-9 and pls set each one to go activity1-9, also how can i use just 1 xml file? i saw in your code still we use 9 xml (i make 9 xml just for duration)

Comment: fixed erors, its working, just how use just 1 xml?! also how to set shake animation for all too (on press)?

Comment: i don`t want to change it, i mean use something like new Pair(R.id.Button01, 1000l), and use 1 xml file instead of 9 file. also i have an other method for buttons, shake animation on press. now in my code i just use for one button, i want to use this animation for all buttons too, also each buttons go to an other activity after shake animation, do you understand what is my means?

Comment: Yes, I think so, give me a few second I will update my code

Comment: i`m so sorry, i just very Curious, Imagine our 9 button names are something like btn_N(1-9), also we have 9 activity with names something like Activity_N(1-9), so we want this happend after click: btn_1 go to Activity_1, btn_2 go to activity_2 and ... of curse all must have shake animation on press and change activity with an other animation. yah, if we use for method, i think we will have best code

Comment: My actually solution do this for you. Just set proper name of activity

Comment: yess it is perfect, thank you so much, just my animation is push left to right but now it is right to left

Comment: I am glad that I could help you

Comment: :) it is so good, can i have a contact way to you pls?! skype or ...

Comment: If you have any problem I think that StackOverFlow is the best place to post it. If you want to help from me. Just ping me by comment I will help you. I am on Stack very often

Comment: ok thanks, just my animation is push left to right but now it is doing right to left ! can you fix it pls?

Comment: post your xml animation or send me link with this code/xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="1000"/>
 <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="1000" />
</set>

Comment: are you sure that you use this animation? it looks fine. Maybe you use different. Check that the name of this animation is the same as name of animation which you use in code

Comment: it was from         Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.your_animation);

Comment: Kornard how can i play a soud while performing Animation? i mean is above code animation not other animations

Comment: I'm not specialist with that :) But you can ask one more time on new post to more clarity and better understanding your problem

Comment: i read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809455/how-to-play-sound-in-while-performing-certain-animation-in-android

but i can`t change your code for animation to that format

Comment: Basically I newer do this but it can be helpful for you http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-soundpool-example/

Comment: You should focus on playSound and stopSound method. you have to call something similar on onAnimationStart and onAnimationEnd methods.

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak can you help in this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29173211/how-to-setimageresource-in-listview/29173325

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can create method

```
private void buttonAnim(int buttonId, long duration){
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(buttonId);
        Animation anim=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,your_anim_id);
        anim.setDuration(duration);
        b.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

And use it to call your animation for ex:

```
buttonAnim(R.anim.Button06, 1000);
```

Additionally you can put your buttons in array and do it in loop as is shown in the code below:

```
int[] buttonsArrays = new int { 
                   R.anim.Button01,
                   R.anim.Button02,
                   R.anim.Button06,
                   ...
                   }

int[] durations = new int { 
                   1000,
                   5000,
                   1000,
                   ...
                   }
```

And in your code:

```
  for(int index=0; index <buttonsArrays.length; index++){
      buttonAnim(buttonsArrays[index],durations[index]); 
  }
```

But remember the lengths of arrays have to be the same

Or you can use `Pair` object as is shown in the code below:

```
    Pair<Integer, Long>[] pairs = new Pair[]{
            new Pair(R.id.Button01, 1000l),
            new Pair(R.id.Button02, 5000l),
            ...
    };
```

And in your code:

```
  for(Pair<Integer,Long> pair : pairs ){
      buttonAnim(pair.first,pair.second); 
  }
```

It will be most save

**EDIT**

Please find my proposition of your class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private final ButtonSupport[] buttonSupports = new ButtonSupport[]{
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button06,1000l, YourClassActivity.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button03, 2000l,YourClassActivity2.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.button1, 3000l,YourClassActivity3.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button08, 4000l,YourClassActivity4.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button04, 5000l,YourClassActivity5.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button01, 6000l,YourClassActivity6.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button07, 7000l,YourClassActivity7.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button05, 8000l,YourClassActivity8.class),
            new ButtonSupport(R.id.Button02, 9000l,YourClassActivity9.class),
    };

    private static class ButtonSupport{
        final int buttonId;
        final long duration;
        final Class<? extends Activity> clazz;

        ButtonSupport(int buttonId, long duration, Class<? extends Activity> clazz) {
            this.buttonId = buttonId;
            this.duration = duration;
            this.clazz = clazz;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        for (ButtonSupport buttonSupport : buttonSupports) {
            animButton(buttonSupport);
        }

    }

    private void animButton(final ButtonSupport buttonSupport) {
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(buttonSupport.buttonId);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startButtonAnimation(v, buttonSupport.clazz);
            }
        });
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.your_animation);
        anim.setDuration(buttonSupport.duration);
        button.startAnimation(anim);
    }

    public void startButtonAnimation(View btn, final Class<? extends  Activity> clazz) {
        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
        btn.setAnimation(shake);
        btn.startAnimation(shake);

        shake.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), clazz));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2);
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```