# how to setImageResource in listview?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, imageview

i store image name in sqlite, i get names with a query and i need to set image resource.
i try this :

```
ImageView img_categlist = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_categlist);
int imageid = getResources().getIdentifier(Image[position], "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

img_categlist.setImageResource(imageid);    

int save = db.sh_categtest("charterdb", "test");
Image = new String [save];

for (int i = 0; i <save; i++) {
    Image[i]= db.nam_nametest("charterdb", "test", i, 15);
}
```

but it is not working, how should i do it?
(images are in drawable and i just store names in sqlite)

Full code:

```
public class Barayetest extends ListActivity {

private database db;
private String[] Name;
private String[] Price;
private String[] Image;

@Override   
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_barayetest);
db = new database(this);

refresher();
setListAdapter(new AA());

}

class AA extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

public AA() {
super(Barayetest.this, R.layout.categ_item, Name);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater in = getLayoutInflater();
View row = in.inflate(R.layout.categ_item, parent, false);

TextView txt_cat = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_cat);
txt_cat.setText(Name [position]);

TextView txt_numb = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_numb);
txt_numb.setText(String.valueOf(position+1));

TextView txt_price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txt_price);
txt_price.setText(Price [position]);
int imageid = getResources().getIdentifier(Image[position], "drawable", getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

ImageView img_categlist = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_categlist);
img_categlist.setImageResource(imageid);        

return (row);
}
}
private void refresher(){
db.open();
int save = db.sh_categtest("charterdb", "test");
Name = new String [save];
Price = new String [save];
Image = new String [save];

for (int i = 0; i <save; i++) {

Name[i]= db.nam_nametest("charterdb", "test", i, 2);
Price[i]= db.nam_nametest("charterdb", "test", i, 7);
Image[i]= db.nam_nametest("charterdb", "test", i, 15);
}


db.close();
}
    }
```

Comment: You use wrong method to get it. If you put your image in drawable you don't have to put name for its in db. You can just use `R.drawable.drawable_name`, I think that you choose wrong way. You should describe what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
After your updated code, you have to get **ImageView from View row**. So use like,

```
ImageView img_categlist = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.img_categlist);
img_categlist.setImageResource(imageid);
```

Comment: no it is not null, i update my question and i put full code. when i set text image[position], i can see image names in listview